# How can I correctly send and receive data with a GroupSessionMessenger?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, facetime

I currently try to setup SharePlay for my app, but when I try to receive and send data with the GroupSessionMessenger I always get the following errors:

`No exact matches in call to instance method ‘messages’` and `No exact matches in call to instance method ‘send’`

Does anyone know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through my code for a while, I found out, that it seems like those are some kind of generic error messages. The real problem was that my model **did not conform to the Codable** protocol. So just let the model you are trying to receive/send with the messenger conform to Codable and you should be good to go!

I also stumbled upon some more problems, therefore, I also set up [a whole tutorial](https://mitemmetim.medium.com/shareplay-tutorial-share-custom-data-between-ios-and-macos-a50bfecf6e64) on how to setup SharePlay between iOS and MacOS if someone's interested.